# selenium and IE

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer

How can I get this working. 
I am unable to get IE working with selenium on python. I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "iedriver.py", line 2, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\Python27\IEDriverServer.exe")   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line 55, in __init__
desired_capabilities=capabilities)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 91, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in start_session
'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 106, in check_response
status = value["status"] KeyError: 'status'
```

below is my code and additional details:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\Python27\IEDriverServer.exe")
```

IEDriverServer I have is 32bit version 3.9
Windows 8

Selenium 2.53.2

Comment: Why IE,it is too slow

Comment: What  is ur IEDriver and selenium version

Comment: The reason why i have to use IE is because of vbscript only being supported in IE.... :(

Comment: Selenium 2.53.2 and IEdriverserver 3.9 version

Comment: update selenium and try

Comment: that solved it for me thanks, you can put this as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get any **unexpected** error, first make sure all the things are **up-to-date**.

Here update selenium worked.